# regex \w in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, reactjs

i want a regex so that it matches everything in \w but not an _

say suppose i have an regex `^[\w\s\,\']*$` in java script
and i want to exclude _ in the above expression  if use the regex like this `^[^\W_\s\,\']*$` 
it is not working because it is not accepting the , and ' and \s also 
Thanks in advance

Comment: `(?!_)\w` ..........

Comment: A better one is `[^\W_]`